# Apply GZIP to SVG - WebConfig

Tags: asp.net, svg, web-config, iis-7.5, gzip

I have both static and dynamic content compression enabled in my web site

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90" dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="70">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

I examined .aspx, .js and .css files Content-Encoding - It's gzip - so far so good. However compression is not applied to SVGs. PageSpeed also notifies me about this (YSlow doesn't... ?).

I use SVGs both as image src attribute and CSS class. (Is CSS class considered to be a dynamic content?)

IIS static compression is set to compress only files larger that 500 bytes - all of those SVGs are above this limit.

Both static and dynamic compression mods are installed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are your .svg files served up with the correct content type (image/svg+xml)?

When served without a proper Content-Type in the response, the compression modules will not compress the response.

Comment: Hey, the content type seems to be OK

Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: image/svg+xml

I added even <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" /> to WebConfig